# Row count for a column

Tags: count, jasper-reports, report

In my subreport I want do display for eg.

```
Number of clients born in 1972: 34
```

So in the database I have a list of their birth years

How can I display this number in a field?

Here is a Sample of the data:

```
<Born>  <Name>                     <BleBle>
1981    Mnr EH Van Niekerk          9517
1982    MEV A BELL                  9520
1972    Mnr GI van der Westhuize    9517
1987    Mnr A Juyn                  9517
1983    Mev MJC Prinsloo            9513
1972    Mnr WA Van Rensburg         9517
1989    Kmdt EL Van Der Colff       9514
1972    Mnr JS Jansen Van Vuuren    9517
```

So if this was all the data the output would have to be

```
Number of clients born in 1972: 3
```

Comment: Post the query from your report.

Comment: its just a simple select query, I need to know how to count and display a certain value in a field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a variable BORN_IN_1972.
2. Set its "Variable class" to java.lang.Integer.
3. Set "Calculation" to "Count".
4. Set "Variable Expression" to $F{Born}.
5. Set "Initial Value Expression" to 0.

[image: Screenshot form iReport Designer]

Than add "Summary" band to your report. And put static text "Number of clients born in 1972:" and text field "$V{BORN_IN_1972}" into it.

[image]

Comment: Thx This works but is there any way I can use that variable above the detail line ? eg. the Page header

Comment: 1. You can count your clients in JAVA code that generates the report and send the value as a parameter.

Comment: 2. You can create subreport (that consists of summary band only and counts your clients) in Page Header, but you should send to subreport your main report datasouce as a parameter with type JRDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming birth year is a string:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyClients
WHERE birth_year = '1972'
```

And if birth year is being used as an input control:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyClients
WHERE birth_year = $P{birth_year}
```

Comment: Will this work in iReport ? if so, where do i put the SQL code ?

Comment: Here is a link to the Jaspersoft documentation: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation?version=9036. Scroll down to the bottom to get the document for iReport.

Answer (score 0):

To count non-zero records in jasper use the expression below -

```
( $F{test} == 0.0 ? null : $F{test} )
```